# Invariant of KdV equations

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

This is something I saw in a paper. Let me describe it below:

> Consider the KdV equation on $(0,1)$ subject to the periodic boundary conditions for all derivatives:
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> \frac{d}{dt}u + D^3 u +  u D u  & = 0 \\
>     u(0) & = u_0
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
> where $D$ denotes the spacial derivative.
> We consider following invariant of the equation:
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> L(v) := \int_0^1 (D^2 v)^2 - \frac{5}{3} v(Dv)^2 + \frac{5}{36}v^4.
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
> We could compute the Frechet derivative for $L$
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> \langle L'(v), h \rangle := \int_0^1 2(D^2v)(D^2h) - \frac{5}{3}(Dv)^2 h - \frac{5}{3} D(v^2)Dh + \frac{5}{9}v^3h
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
> Then it is claimed that $\langle L'(u), D^3 u +  u D u \rangle = 0$, where $u$ solves the KdV equation.

I am not able to prove this fact. It should follow from integration by parts, but I failed to play with those many terms. I think one property for $L$ is that $\langle L(u), D^3 u +  u D u \rangle = 0$, could we derive $\langle L'(u), D^3 u +  u D u \rangle = 0$ from here? Could anyone do a bit of computation for me?

Edit: We could assume everything is smooth at this moment.

Comment: It seems that the last term of $\langle L'(v), h\rangle$ should be $\frac59v^3h$, NOT $\frac12v^3h$. Could you provide a link to the paper you are reading?

Comment: @Feng Yes you are right! It is $\frac{5}{9}v^3 h$. I am sorry for the typo. The author is using another set of coefficients different from mine, and I accidentally put theirs down.  Would you mind writing a bit the computation process for me?

Comment: @Feng The paper I am reading is: "On the long-time statistical behavior of smooth solutions of the weakly damped, stochastically-driven KdV equation". Here is the arxiv link: https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.12942

Comment: Sorry. I was unable to deduce the relation $\langle L'(u), u\rangle=0$. The term with $u^4$ confuses me. Could you point out where does the claim appear in the paper? I find the definition of the functionals in Section 2.2, but I cannot find the claim you quoted.

Comment: @Feng I am sorry again, I mean $\langle L'(u), D^3 u +  u D u \rangle = 0$. Originally I fixed it in the last paragraph but not in the quoting block.

Comment: @Feng This claim is not explicit in the paper, it is in the proof for Lemma A.3. See the equation between (A.19) and (A.20), which was obtained by applying Ito's formula to equation (A.2) w.r.t. functional $L_2$. Then it should contain $\langle L'(u), D^3u + uDu \rangle$ there. Observe that this term does NOT interact with $\epsilon, \gamma, \eta, \xi$, so we could identify it easily if it is non-zero. But we cannot find this term, and that's why I think it is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $u$ is a smooth solution of the KdV equation. We denote $h=D^3u+uDu$ ,
$$I_1=\int_0^1D^2uD^2h,\ \  I_2=\int_0^1(Du)^2h,\ \  I_3=\int_0^1u(Du)(Dh),\ \ I_4=\int_0^1u^3h, $$
and
$$A=\int_0^1Du(D^2u)^2,\qquad B=\int_0^1u(Du)^3.$$
Then
$$\langle L'(u), h\rangle=2I_1-\frac53I_2-\frac{10}3I_3+\frac59I_4.$$

> In the following we prove that $\langle L'(u), h\rangle=0$.

Notation: $\int=\int_0^1$.

We have $I_1=\int D^2u(D^5u+D^2(uDu))$. Since
$$\int D^2uD^5u=-\int D^3uD^4u=-\int D^3uD(D^3u)=-\frac12\int D((D^3u)^2)=0,$$
we have
\begin{align*}
I_1&=\int D^2u D^2(uDu)=\int D^2u(3Du D^2u+u D^3u)=3\int Du(D^2u)^2+\int uD^2uD^3u\\
&=3\int Du(D^2u)^2+\frac12\int u D((D^2u)^2)=\frac52\int Du(D^2u)^2=\frac52A.
\end{align*}
For $I_2$, we have
\begin{align*}
I_2&=\int (Du)^2D^3u+\int u(Du)^3=\int (Du)^2D(D^2u)+B\\
&=-2\int Du(D^2u)^2+B=-2A+B.
\end{align*}
For $I_3$, we have
\begin{align*}
I_3&=\int u Du D^4u+\int u Du D(u Du)=\int D^2(u Du)D^2u+\frac12\int D((u Du)^2)\\
&=I_1+0=\frac52A.
\end{align*}
For $I_4$, we have
\begin{align*}
I_4&=\int u^3D^3u+\int u^4 Du=\int D^2(u^3)Du+\frac15\int D(u^5)\\
&=\int 6u(Du)^3+3u^2D^2uDu=6B+\frac32\int u^2D((Du)^2)\\
&=6B-3\int u(Du)^3=3B.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\langle L'(u), h\rangle=0$.